# Ways to backup MySQL databases regularly?

Tags: php, mysql, database, backup

I'd like to know what options do you recommend when it comes to backing up the information stored in MySQL databases.

Maybe there are some ready solutions/plugins available that I can install on my server to run daily/weekly backups?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What server do you use? In Linux you can take dump of mysql with the command `mysqldump` and put it in the `cronjob` for continuous backuping. And also with bash script, you can name your files as the backing up date.

Comment: You can use both commands in plesk server too

Answer (score 0):

I run a unix bash command using crontab, i have a backup folder `/var/www/backup`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove old backup files (after 7 days)
find /var/www/backup -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;

# Create a backup file with today's date filename
TIME=`date +"%Y-%m-%B-%d"`
FILENAME="backup-$TIME.tar.gz"

# Compress the backup data
tar -cpzf /var/www/backup/$FILENAME /var/lib/mysql --exclude /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I excluded the mysql.sock file because that's the socket service (no need), this script backs up ALL databases... so you could change this line for a specific database

```
tar -cpzf /var/www/backup/$FILENAME /var/lib/mysql/DATABASE
```

Comment: This strategy can be tricky - since the database might not be "safe" for a file system backup.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/backup-methods.html the "Filesystem Snapshot" section.

Answer (score 0):

As Prof83 said you can create a bash file and then run it automatically with a cronjob.
An interesting thing I would point out is that you could use Dropbox for making offsite backups by extending the bash script from this one: https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader/blob/master/dropbox_uploader.sh

Comment: Or, if you feel like a challenge, setup a remote SVN server